# How to prevent Mono from being cancelled?

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to implement something as a "race condition". This race condition must follow these situations:

- Fire two simultaneous HTTP calls.
- Return the response from the first call that was completed successfully.
- Handle the last call. (The most important thing here is that I can not discard the last call, I do need to handle the result of it: whatever its status, success or fail).

This sample of code is the most close of the solution that I have achieved:

```
    Mono<StatusMock> monoA = webClient.get()
      .uri("https://some.url.a")
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(StatusMock.class)
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());

    Mono<StatusMock> monoB = webClient.get()
      .uri("https://some.url.b")
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(StatusMock.class)
      .doOnSuccess(this::verifyBody)
      .onErrorStop()
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());

    StatusMock statusMock = Flux.first(monoA, monoB)
      .blockFirst();

    if (statusMock != null) {
      return statusMock.getStatus();
    }

    return "empty";
  }

  private void verifyBody(StatusMock statusMock) {
    if (statusMock.getStatus().contains("error")) {
      log.error("throwing an exception");
      throw new RuntimeException("error");
    }
  }
```

```
public class StatusMock {

  private String status; // getters and setters implicit
}
```

In this example I used the Flux.first method, and it helps me a lot returning the first call, but it discards (cancel) the second one which is a problem since I need the result of the last call as well.

Is there any solution to this logic? Here I am using Spring Project Reactor, but I accept any library or framework that could help me with this situation.

Comment: Just stick both urls in a flux, do flatMap (it is async and will do both calls simultanious) then collect list, block to get the list select first and do whatever, select second and do whatever.

Comment: @Toerktumlare this does not work, because the block method will force a waiting of monoA + monoB and I need to return an answer of the first successfully call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cache` operator on the `Mono`s to prevent them from being cancelled:

```java
    Mono<StatusMock> monoA = webClient.get()
      // ...
      .cache();

    Mono<StatusMock> monoB = webClient.get()
      // ...
      .cache();

    Mono.firstWithSignal(monoA, monoB);
```