# Spring Reactor Mono or Flux, how to get first signal but still let the rest run through?

Tags: project-reactor

I have 2 asynchronous Monos, I'd like to start processing immediately whenver a result is available.

I am looking at the Reactor API `firstWithSignal` that seems promising. but problem is it cancels the later one as soon as one result is returned.

Is there a way I can keep both run through but can continue with whichever result that is available?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69990519/8909235

Comment: Your problem looks similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69055040/6051176

Comment: @MartinTarjányi thank you. I saw that one, but it seems unintuitive. I am just thinking there must be some way to be able run/finish all tasks.

Comment: @Ikatiforis that is not what I am looking for. I want the caller returns as soon as one of the result is available.